# Getting OG data impossible because of CORB

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to scrape OG data using `open-graph-scraper` and Vue.js, but it gets blocked because of CORB in Chrome. It is working fine for scripts I run using Node, but is there a work around for this problem or another to get OG data from an input URL?

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response SOME-INPUT-URL with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

CORB is a standard that is based around the idea 
"what I asked for is what I received"

if you are troubleshooting CORB errors in chrome it means that your request method is being responded to with either no content type or a content type that does not correspond to your method of request.

in a 3rd party API what I would recommend is using a tool like postman (unaffiliated) to inspect the incoming content type in the response headers. Once you know the content-type header of the call then tweak your request method in an attempt to match the expected output. Many API's use poorly implemented frameworks so just because the response is well formed JSON doesn't mean that the header will say JSON. I often see json outputs where the headers are 'text/plain'.

If this doesn't work, for example some api's fail to respond with content headers at all
- another method would be to use an intermediary call to make the request. For example using a combination of the AWS API gateway and a AWS Lambda function you can create a route that will make the request using node but where you then gain the total control over both the response headers and body. You can then add the content header you desire and pass it back to your client.

ref:
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers